# url with hebrew chars returns giberish (404) from apache

Tags: apache-2.4, utf-8

moving wordpress site with wpml template to a new server

when I click on a url that contians hebrew letters I get this results form apache (the url at the new page is correct and display the right letters in hebrew):

Not Found
The requested URL /category/×ž××ž×¨×™×/ was not found on this server.

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: That doesn't look like Hebrew. Where do you see the correct URL?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show the hebrew string or even full requested URL.